# Calling Haskell from Node.JS

Tags: node.js, haskell, rpc

I want to make RPC calls of Haskell code from Node.js. What libraries exist for both node and Haskell? I could only found XML-RPC and zeromq, but they seem to be unstable.

Answer (score 2):

for xml-rpc on the Haskell side, the haxr library has been around for a long time and remains supported: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxr-3000.8.5

Comment: https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc is an XML-RPC client and server for Node.js. It's actively developed and should be stable.